# Difference between method type and value in Scala

Tags: scala

Reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2530007/824644) he speaks about "Methods Values" but right in the next paragraph he says that "A Method Type is a non-value type. That means there is no value". Isn't this contradictory? In Scala, does a method have a value or not?

I know that we can't assign a method to a variable (without turning it into a function by using `_`), isn't this enough to say that a method **does not** have a value?

Comment: Read that fully: at one point there's the "we do not use that terminology" part. SO, instead of having a concept, you have concepts and multiple words that map to them in overlapping and possibly conflicting ways...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `m` is a `method` then the `method value` is `m_` which is actually a function. So it has a `function type` .
A method value has a function type. 
A method type is just the `def` statement without the body. It cannot be used anywhere!
This is how i look at it.